# Subsetting rows by the most recent date from one column

Tags: r, database, date, dplyr

### Goal

I am currently trying to take all unique dates in `charttime`, and examine if there is a date `charttime.repletion` that occurs within 24 hours after charttime. If so, I would like to flag it for later analysis. It is important that I keep `charttime`s that don't meet this criteria too. The catch is that I want to take only the first charttime.repletion for each charttime (and subsequently each valuenum), if there are multiple dates within the given 24 hour window.

#### Background

The `charttime` dates are associated with a labvalue (`valuenum`), and a respective `subject_id` and `hadm_id`. This is also true of the `charttime.repletion` column, which you can also see in the tables below. The problem is, as far as I know,  because there are many valuenums, `charttime`s and `charttime.repletions` for a respective `hadm_id` and `subject_id`, it created an enormous table with nearly 15,000,000 rows (with rows being in the hundreds of thousands prior to joining).

#### What I've done so far

This is the able I'm working with:

```
 subject_id hadm_id icustay_id itemid.repletion charttime.repletion  cgid linkorderid itemid charttime           valuenum valueuom label     flag  fluid category 
        <int>   <int>      <int>            <int> <dttm>              <int>       <int>  <int> <dttm>                 <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>    
 1         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 15805    11400165  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
 2         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 17701    11825098  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
 3         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 15805    11400165  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
 4         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 15805    11400165  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
 5         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 15805    11400165  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
 6         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 17701    11825098  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
 7         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 17701    11400165  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
 8         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 15805    11400165  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
 9         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 17701    11400165  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
10         11  194540     229441            30026 2178-04-17 00:00:00 17701    11400165  50971 2178-04-15 00:00:00      3.8 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry
# … with 15,494,874 more rows
```

And this is my attempt at the problem it:

```
    dfPotassiumMethod2 %>%
      mutate(pre.replete = if_else(condition = (charttime.repletion > charttime) & 
      (charttime.repletion <= (charttime + 24*3600 )), 
      true = "yes", false = "no")) %>%
      group_by(charttime.repletion) %>%
      slice_max(order_by = charttime) -> pre_repetionK
```

When I do this, my output is this:

```
 12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 17478     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no         
 2      12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 17454     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no         
 3      12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 19610     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no         
 4      12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 17478     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no         
 5      12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 17478     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no         
 6      12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 17454     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no         
 7      12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 17454     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no         
 8      12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 17454     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no         
 9      12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 17478     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no         
10      12001  173927     222148            30026 2100-06-14 00:00:00 17478     3120908  50971 2100-06-25 00:00:00        4 mEq/L    Potassium NA    Blood Chemistry no
```

I know the timestamp in the `charttime.repletion` column says zero, but I believe tibble is just failing to show those for some reason, and they are actually all different time values. I am just confused, because I there should only be one `valuenum` (4mEq/L), corresponding to whatever `valuenum` was closest to it in `charttime`.

Is this a good methodology? How would I go about validating my results, in any case?

I appreciate any input you can offer on this matter.

### Process of preparing the data

---

This is my process for creating the data so far.

I started with this table so far:

```
      subject_id hadm_id icustay_id itemid.repletion charttime.repletion  cgid linkorderid
        <int>   <int>      <int>            <int> <dttm>              <int>       <int>
 1      21842  174955     250436            30026 2140-11-24 17:00:00 21570     8594378
 2      21857  173189     269052            30026 2116-11-05 18:00:00 20963    11951770
 3      19339  126827     261452            30297 2114-01-08 16:00:00 18197     3512345
 4      25438  169622     240384            30297 2107-01-31 16:00:00 18708     2133610
 5       9175  148433     218471            30026 2194-12-20 10:00:00 14973    11207445
 6      18605  173380     264352            30026 2188-12-13 10:00:00 14597      592655
 7       6960  178048     298934            30026 2120-11-24 00:00:00 19050      109745
 8      18605  173380     264352            30026 2188-12-14 00:00:00 19050      592655
 9      21842  174955     250436            30026 2140-11-21 02:00:00 15690     6813841
10      18028  160399     204739            30026 2131-01-22 02:00:00 15928     5325139
# … with more rows
```

where I left-joined it by the columns `subject_id` and `hadm_id`, on this table:

```
subject_id hadm_id itemid charttime           valuenum valueuom label     flag     fluid category 
        <int>   <int>  <int> <dttm>                 <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr> <chr>    
 1          3      NA  50971 2101-10-13 03:00:00      4.3 mEq/L    Potassium NA       Blood Chemistry
 2          3      NA  50971 2101-10-13 15:47:00      4   mEq/L    Potassium NA       Blood Chemistry
 3          3      NA  50971 2101-10-14 03:00:00      3.7 mEq/L    Potassium NA       Blood Chemistry
 4          3      NA  50971 2101-10-15 03:30:00      4   mEq/L    Potassium NA       Blood Chemistry
 5          3      NA  50971 2101-10-15 12:15:00      4.2 mEq/L    Potassium NA       Blood Chemistry
 6          3      NA  50971 2101-10-16 04:00:00      3.5 mEq/L    Potassium NA       Blood Chemistry
 7          3      NA  50971 2101-10-16 15:30:00      4.9 mEq/L    Potassium NA       Blood Chemistry
 8          3      NA  50971 2101-10-18 05:25:00      4.4 mEq/L    Potassium NA       Blood Chemistry
 9          3  145834  50971 2101-10-20 16:40:00      5.4 mEq/L    Potassium abnormal Blood Chemistry
10          3  145834  50971 2101-10-22 04:00:00      4.3 mEq/L    Potassium NA       Blood Chemistry
# … with more rows
```

Using this function:

```
tbl_mimic(inputevents_cv) %>%
  semi_join(kCVSearch, by = "itemid") %>%
  select(subject_id, hadm_id, icustay_id, itemid, charttime,  cgid,  linkorderid) %>%
  rename(itemid.repletion = itemid, charttime.repletion = charttime) %>% 
  left_join(labEventsK, by=c("subject_id", "hadm_id")) %>%
  collect() -> dfPotassiumMethod2
```

*Edit:*
Where `tbl_mimic` is a function that retrieves a given table from the postgres backend.

```
 tbl_mimic <- function(table) {
      table <- as.character(substitute(table))
      tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema("mimiciii", table))
    }
```

Comment: Do you want a SQL solution, or a dplyr solution?

Comment: @Mousa . . . I removed the SQL tag.  This looks like an R question.  If the data is really in a database, then be explicit about the database and what the tables look like.

Comment: Sorry, did not intend to be misleading. I am using R with a Postgres backend and dbplyr @GordonLinoff

Comment: @GMB I would prefer a dplyr solution

Comment: What is `tbl_mimic`?

Comment: @r2evans It is a function that retrieves a given table from the database I am using `tbl_mimic <- function(table) {
  table <- as.character(substitute(table))
  tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema("mimiciii", table))
}`  
I have included it here just for reference.

Comment: If it is important to your process, then please include it in your question. If it is not crucial, then remove it from your question. Comments are not a good place for critical pieces of information like that, though, since comments can easily be skipped by readers or hidden in the interface. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans That's a good point, and I agree! I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little too many things going on in your question and there's no toy dataset for people to jump on, so that's the challenging part. But if I understand your intention correctly, here's a toy example and how I solve it.

If you never use `lubridate` package to manipulate date/datetime object, you should... Here I conveniently use its `ymd_hms()` function to create datetime object. Using datetime object you can easily do comparison and mathematics with it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#### Fake data
set.seed(4326)
random_hrs <- runif(20, 12, 30)

df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(c(1, 2), each = 10),
  charttime = rep(ymd_hms(c("2020-05-05 12:01:00", "2020-05-04 13:02:01",
                            "2020-03-05 12:01:00", "2020-03-06 13:02:01")), each = 5)
)

df$charttime.repletion <- df$charttime + dhours(random_hrs)

df

#### Flag rows with charttime.repletion - charttime <= 24 hrs
## difftime function ensures difference in time is measured by hours
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(flag = (difftime(charttime.repletion, charttime, units = "hours") <= 24) & (difftime(charttime.repletion, charttime, units = "hours") >= 0))

#### Take only rows with flag == TRUE
df2 <- df1 %>%
  filter(flag)
df2

#### For each id x charttime combination, take the row with lowest chartime.repletion
df2 %>%
  group_by(id, charttime) %>%
  mutate(anotherflag = charttime.repletion == min(charttime.repletion)) %>%
  filter(anotherflag)
```